# Phalcon - How to hide get parametres in URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, phalcon

I have a url like

```
localhost/case?id=name
```

How do I hide the id part without routing by using htaccess and just show:

```
localhost/case/name
```

p.s. framework phalcon

htaccess have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why you don't wanna use routing ?

Comment: @Juri i'm trying to use .htaccess , but if it does not work , I will use a router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#if our requested file isn't a dir, and isn't a file, and isn't a symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#then skip our next rule below
RewriteRule .* - [S=1]
#since we got here, the file exists, so don't rewrite it, skip the next two rules
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
#these two rules are bound to our condition i.e. if the link is broken
RewriteRule ^case/([^/]*)$ index.php?_url=/case&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
#end of our two rules which would be skipped if our condition was false
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^case/([^/]*)$ /case?id=$1 [L]
```